# Check if processor is arm64

Tags: ios, arm64

Is there a simple Objective-C IF statement that can be written to check if the processor in an iOS device is arm64?

The reason that this is needed is that some Core Audio code written for 32-bit architectures is crashing for arm64. It seems that replacing Int16 references with Int32 may resolve it, but I need an IF statement to determine the processor type to determine which to use.

It could be done just by looking for specific device types, but a processor type check seems like a more elegant and future-proofed solution.

Comment: Unless you are doing some hardware specific stuff you're probably doing it wrong if you need to query the architecture. So you're better off asking a new question and posting your code that is crashing: if replacing `Int16` with `Int32` solves your problem then something is very, very wrong with your code to begin with.

Comment: Your right that changing to Int32 didn't resolve it. After intializing a Remote Audio Unit on arm64 the app crashes in various ways e.g. *** error for object 0x17420b080: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** or AURemoteIO::IOThread EXC_BAD_ACCESS. There is a lot of code in there, I don't know where to begin. Any tips?

Comment: Check all the types involved, for example with Core Audio, a sample is usually of type `UInt32`, `Int32` or `Float32`. Avoid types with no clear size (`int`, `long`, etc.) If you're using structs, you might need `__attribute__((packed))`. The message you're citing comes from wrong memory/pointer management so check your `malloc`/`free` calls if you're doing any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There no official way to get this information, but you can compare pointer's size to get this it during the runtime:

```
if (sizeof(void*) == 4) {
    NSLog(@"32-bit app");
} else if (sizeof(void*) == 8) {
    NSLog(@"64-bit app");
}
```